# Do get and give have same meaning in this context?

Tags: word-usage

Do get an give have same meaning in these two expressions?

> I got him the tickets of the concert.
>
> I gave him the tickets of the concert.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, they do not mean the same thing.

"Got" means obtained, usually by buying. The sentence means "I obtained the tickets for him."

"Gave" means transferred possession to him, or "handed them over."

> Therefore, after I "got" him the tickets, I then "gave" them to him.

You see how that would work?

Also, we would say "to" the concert, not "of" the concert.